# Sonarqube data migration

Tags: sonarqube, migration

I was following https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters if it can help for project migration from one sonar to another, but no luck.
Currently I was having sonar(6.3 version community) in one server that has all projects and data, now I'd like to migrate or move the the sonar (6.3 version community) and its data to an another server that has sonar (7.0 version community). what would be the easy approach.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy approach from where you currently sit. There is a feature available with [Enterprise Edition](https://www.sonarsource.com/plans-and-pricing/enterprise/)($) which would allow you to move a project from one *identically configured* instance of SonarQube to another. But there's no provision for incrementing SonarQube version along the way.

Comment: Thanks Ann for the quick response, actually i was assuming the below approach. The server (sonar 6.3 community version has local DB i.e mysql installed in same server), and i believe data will be stored in DB, we can migrate the data (DB) to another DB server (sonar 7.0 community version that uses DB which is in another server i.e mysql installed in anothe server not the server where sonar 7.0 installed.). would this be possible ?